# DIV tags behaving strangely

Tags: css, html

My private webpage's main content is not displaying strangely within Firefox. The header and footer bar both display and the main text is placed adjacent to them towards the right. Occasionally, the footer also moves above the main text. I'm guessing this is all one issue involving the positioning of DIVs that I'm somehow missing. [This has been solved]

The height of two DIVs that are equally as tall when displayed in Chrome is also different. This issue also occurs in Safari but in a different way. There is a 1 px gap between the logo and the navbar that isn't present when viewed in Chrome or Firefox. Can anyone think of a way to reset all of the browser defaults to prevent similar things from happening in the future?

The website is currently not online yet and I'm debugging it for final release. (I don't really want to release this in the current condition as it will frustrate anyone who doesn't use a webkit browser.)

Also, as a side note, anyone know how to fix the CSS errors I'm getting in Internet Explorer 9? The gradient in the nav bar is gone, some areas have missing background color, and all picture links have annoying boxes around them.

EDIT: I saw in an online CSS gradient generator what I need to do to make the gradients work in IE9. The background issue apparently stems from the same source.

Also, is anyone in Opera experiencing issues with the latest debug version at http://jsbin.com/ipixay/1? (Credit for this one goes to Sunyatasattva.)

The link to the fiddle (where the code is posted at) is: [http://jsfiddle.net/aaQSD/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/aaQSD/6/) Please forgive me for the amount of CSS that's still there, but I can't tell which causes the Internet Explorer 9 problems.

My best guess is that the Firefox problem lies somewhere in this section of CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Times;
    background: #efefef url(pics/background.png) repeat top center;
}
#container {
    overflow:auto;
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 946px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}
#content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#content-inner {
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
.center-slide {
    font: normal 62.5%/1.5 Times;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    width: 900px;
    height: 485px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.boxes {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
.left-box {
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.logo {
    width: 26%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    font-family: Times;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 22px 90deg, #0B3474, #517ABA);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 70%, from(#517ABA), to(#0B3474));
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 863px;
    background-color: #000047;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
nav {
    background-color: #6a6a6a;
    font: 16px Times;
    min-width: 700px;
    float: right;
    width: 74%;
}
footer {
    font-family: Times;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000047;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 863px;
}
```

Here is the list of things that have been fixed:

- Unwanted boxes/borders around picture
- Firefox display issue
- Glitchy footer

**EDIT: I'm currently working on making a fiddle with the minimal code to replicate the issue as suggested in the comments. I hope you can forgive me for my noobish mistake. Thanks, everyone who have responded so far!**

**EDIT 2: The fiddle is out! I've removed the pandora's box of code that used to be below.**

Comment: is your website live, so we can take a look ?

Comment: would be easier to include a fiddle/codepen :)

Comment: just to add, here is a [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: now i can only help you about your image links. add rule `a img { border:none; }` and the annoying boxes will disappear. :)

Comment: Please don't dump all your code here - we can't comb through all of it for you. What you will need is to set up a fiddle with the minimal code needed to replicate your issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll work on replicating this issue on a smaller scale, but that might take some time. Thanks trajce for the image border fix.

Comment: I'm kind of new to stack overflow so can anyone explain to me how to use a fiddle? Am I supposed to just paste my code there and removed unnecessary parts? How am I supposed to share this with you? Thanks.

Comment: Paste your code in the appropriate boxes, then click `save` in the header bar and give us the link produced!

Comment: Using a fiddle service like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com) will make it possible for us to work with your minimal code without having to sift around the bigger chunk. Once you *fiddle* with the code there and find a way to replicate your issue, you can just paste the link provided by the website here.

Comment: The fiddle is here everyone. http://jsfiddle.net/aaQSD/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The header and footer are displayed adjacent to the main container

Is there a reason why they are **floated**? Removing the `float: left` rule from the header, makes the container stack below it. If they need to be floated for some reason I am not seeing, perhaps you should consider adding a `clear`?

> Logo height different from navbar element heights

This piece baffled me a bit: I think the culprit is browser default `line-height` property, which, on Chrome, is **coincidentally** making your elements align.

Your nav elements have a set `line-height` of 61, plus a vertical `padding` of 12 on both sides, adding up to 85px. Your logo has no defined `line-height` and a `font-size` of 65px plus a `padding-top` of 10px. In Firefox this is 10px short.

To fix this, just set the `line-height` to your logo element as well.

Here is a working JSBin of your code:

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/ipixay/1)</kbd>

> Internet explorer problems:
>
> - Missing gradient
> - Missing background
> - Annoying border

I don't have IE9 at hand right now, so I might look into it later if you need it, but here are my guesses.

As for the missing gradient, your CSS specifies only webkit and mozilla [vendor prefixes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/11/15/ie9-vendor-prefixes-and-developers.aspx). You might want to take a look at the `-ms–` prefix as well, and check which rules really need it and which don't.

I am skipping the missing background part because it's quite vague and I am not testing on IE right now.

As for the border around linked images, you could perhaps add this rule to your CSS:

```
a img {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Safari annoying one pixel gap

As for the Safari annoying one pixel gap, it apparently comes from the fact that Safari doesn't calculate well your `float: left` + `width: 26%` plus `float: right` + `width: 74%`. Adding a `.1%` to the first element width fixes the problem, but it is not the most elegant solution.

The best solution for your problem at hand is to just float **both your elements** left. You can see an updated fiddle working in Safari:

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/ipixay/6)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! This is very informational and your JSBin works fine in Firefox. I'll look into solving the internet explorer problems. Also, I might have failed to mention this (it'll be included in an edit) but a similar issue as with the line-height problem you mentioned is occur in safari, except this time it's horizontal. there's a 1 pixel gap between the logo and the navbar that does not appear in Firefox and Chrome. Does anyone know of a way to just reset all of the browser defaults?

Comment: Well, you could obviously use a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) or [normalize CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your fiddle for it to work.  I essentially just added `float: left;` to your `#container`.  You can look at my edits for further details. http://jsfiddle.net/aaQSD/8/

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the error, but this also caused even more errors. The footer is behaving strangely and has somehow  moved above the main text and the navigation bar/title box have become misplaced when viewing in any browser.

Comment: Great! I was trying to solve this myself but I see you beat me to it. However, the annoying footer is still crawling it way up above the nav bar.

Comment: try adding `position: relative;` and `float: left;` to your footer class/id.  Also, if you found this to answer your questions, please 1+/mark as answer.  Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/aaQSD/10/

Comment: I would +1, but I don't have 15 rep yet. Saddly, the navbar is still glitching out. Sunyatasattva seems to have fixed everything mentioned here though.